# Converting Google Sheet to Json File, only reading up to 99 data

Tags: php, html, json, google-sheets

When I convert data from Google Sheet to json file, it is only reading up to 99 data and not reading the rest of the data ?
Here's the coding part //The api key is also added in the coding//

```
// Google API Key
$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
// Adding API key to the URL
$urlWithKey = $url . '?key=' . $apiKey;
// Displaying a message to the user
echo "Fetching Data......";
// Fetching the URL contents as HTML
$htmlData = file_get_contents($urlWithKey);
```

I tried adding echo for $htmlData and the data is reading upto 99 only, here is the evidence of it reading up to 99 data (image of 99data). For example, if the data in google sheet is only 50, it is reading the 50 data but if the data in google sheet is more than 99, it is reading only till 99 and not more than that.

How do I make it unlimited data entry ? As when I convert maybe 1000 data, I want it to read and convert to json file.

[image of 99data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An9Ws.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Such APIs usually apply a default limit to the number of results returned in one request. Sometimes they offer a parameter to increase the limit, or you might need to use _pagination_. This should all be explained in the _documentation_ of the API you are using there.

Comment: I tried using pagination method like you said, but now its showing "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded"... i tried increasing the maximum time also